# new Class undefined and net::ERR_ABORTED error on same class

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, class, oop

I have some issues, when creating a new class, it appears as undefined (even though I believe I've done everything right). Also the very same class gives off error of net thingy. I'm not sure what it even means. I have linked it as script in index.

[image: printscreen]

[image: errors]

[image: index scripts load]

I'm honestly not sure what files are relevant, but I can provide with more code if needed.
Thanks!

Comment: If you could supply a snippet here that demonstrates the error it would be easier to help

Comment: Did you load your JS files into the JS file you are using? `<script src="jsFile1.js"></script>`

Comment: I've added new pics of what might be relevant. Yes, I do load all scripts. Not one is missing :)

Comment: Order matters when loading. It looks like app.class.js needs those other two js files in your screenshot, but you load them after you load app.class

Comment: Nothing changed when I switched the order. :/

Comment: `ERR_ABORTED` means the server is getting some kind of error when you're trying to load the `.js` file. Check your server log for details.

Comment: I see you loading 'current-movie.class.js', however, the file name in the first screenshot is 'current-movies.class.js'

Comment: Holy moly! You're right! Thanks! The errors are gone, but no content comes up on the screen now... Which is weird.

Comment: There isn't much to go on as to what your html looks like and what more JS looks like and what exactly you are trying to show on the screen. Seeing how that is a new issue, It would be best to open another question about it, and possibly create a runnable example of your issue in jsbin or codepen or something and link it in your question for people to go to to see your code and try to fix it.